If ideals $I$, $J$, $K$ are pairwise coprime, are $I\cap J$ and $K$ coprime as well?
I do not require rings to have identity in this post.
I was reading this generalized version of Chinese Remainder Theorem which I would summarise as follows:

Let $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^n$ be a collection of ideals of a ring $R$ satisfying $I_k+R^2=R$ and $I_j+I_k=R$ for all distinct $j,k$ then for all $r_1,\ldots, r_n\in R$, the system of congruences: $x\equiv r_k\pmod {I_k} $ has a unique solution modulo $\bigcap_{k=1}^n I_k $.

I was trying to explore why the condition $I_k+ R^2=R$ was needed. In a ring with identity, it's trivially true since $R^2=R$.
From what the language of the proof on the linked page makes me believe, it may happen that in a ring $R$ without identity, there are ideals $I$, $J$, $K$ pairwise coprime i.e., $I+J=J+K=K+I=R$ but $(I\cap J)$ and $K$ are not coprime i.e., $(I\cap J)+K\subsetneq R$.
The condition $K+R^2=R$ would prevent that possibility since:
$R\\=K+R^2\\=K+(K+I)(J+K)\\=K+K^2+KJ+IK+IJ+JI\\ \subseteq K+(I\cap J)$
I can't seem to find an example where ideals $I$, $J$, $K$ are pairwise coprime but $I\cap J$ and $K$ are not. Can anyone help?
My attempt: As it's futile to search in a ring with identity, I searched it in rings like $2\mathbb Z$, $6\mathbb Z$, etc. But it always ended up coprime. There are likely no examples in rings like $n\mathbb Z$. For e.g., in $2\mathbb Z$, I would require $i,j,k$ s.t. $\gcd(i,j)=\gcd(j,k)=\gcd(k,i)=2$ but $\gcd(\text{lcm}(i,j), k)\neq 2$. I would guess that we have to go beyond principal ideal rings to find examples.

In summary, with multiple steps of ideal arithmetic as done in that proof, $I_k+R^2=R$ implies that $I_k + \bigcap_{j\neq k} I_j = R$.

In the last para of your question post, you have shown that the given condition implies $R \subset K + (I \cap J)$.  But since $K + (I \cap J) \subset R$ , does it not follow that $R = K + (I \cap J)$ and that they are indeed coprime ?

@AnuradhaNarasimhan That's what I meant. The condition $K+R^2=R$ prevents the possibility that $K+(I\cap J)\subsetneq R$.

So you are already looked at some examples then? Can you please add them to the post? Then we know where we don't have to look at anymore.

@MartinBrandenburg No, I can't find example for the situation I described i.e., $I,J,K$ are pairwise coprime but $I\cap J$ and $K$ are not. I believe such examples exist because otherwise the condition $I_k+R^2=R$ won't be given in the theorem statement.

Sure. I mean you have looked at examples there the ideals ended up being coprime right? Maybe add them?

@MartinBrandenburg Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. Here's what I tried: As it's futile to search in a ring with identity, I searched it in rings like $2\mathbb Z$, $6\mathbb Z$, etc. But it always ended up coprime. There are likely no examples in rings like $n\mathbb Z$. For e.g., in $2\mathbb Z$, I would require $i,j,k$ s.t. $\gcd(i,j)=\gcd(j,k)=\gcd(k,i)=2$ but $\gcd(\text{lcm}(i,j), k)\neq 2$. I would guess that we have to go beyond principal ideal rings to find examples. [Edited and added this to the body]

Let $R$ have underlying abelian group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (the Klein $4$-group) and zero multiplication. So ideals are the same as subgroups. Take $I$, $J$, and $K$ to be the three distinct subgroups of order $2$. Then $I+J=I+K=J+K=R$, but $I\cap J=\{0\}$ and $(I\cap J)+K = K\neq R$.

It's certainly an example and gives a perspective. I wonder if there are more interesting examples :)

Why should it be not interesting enough? Zero multiplication rngs (i.e. abelian groups) are exactly the guys you invite to your party when you remove the identity element. I bet that any more complex examples are just adaptations of what we see in this perfect answer, only with irrelevant fluff being added. I see this all the actually: when people ask for a non-surjective but injective map I will immediately go with the simplest examples possible, $\emptyset \to {a}$. That's actually the universal example in some sense, so interesting to say the least.

@MartinBrandenburg Yes, I agree. In fact, someone can make this example complicated by taking $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ with the first two components having the zero operation and the third component having usual multiplication. Something like $I\times \mathbb Z$, $J\times \mathbb Z$, $K\times \mathbb Z$ will work. I'll wait for a week or two and then accept this answer. [BTW, you did not tag me so I didn't recieve notification.]

@Nothingspecial If your lack of satisfaction comes from the zero multiplication, take $R=2\mathbb{Z}\times 2\mathbb{Z}$, $I=\langle (2,0),(0,4)\rangle$, $J=\langle (4,0),(0,2)\rangle$, $K=\langle (2,2), (4,0), (0,4)\rangle$. Note it's really the same example pulled back to $R$ from $R/\langle (4,0),(0,4)\rangle$.
